# Eclipse "Open Call Hierarchy" not finding all method calls when editing said method

Tags: java, eclipse

So, before I started editing a method, I could call on the "Open Call Hierarchy" feature and see all the places that the method is called. Everything OK.

However, since I have been editing the method that I am working on (and thus changing the input arguments), now the "Open Call Hierarchy" feature only finds the updated method calls (with the updated input arguments) but not the method calls I still have to update.

So, when the method **was**:

```
public Void X(a, b, c)
```

it could find **all** method calls in the project without any problems. 
However, if I change the method to

```
public Void X(a,b, c, d)
```

Then it will only find the method calls in the project where it is called as X(a, b, c, d). But I will like it to also show me the method calls X(a, b, c) that I haven't updated yet.

Comment: create a temp method with exact same older method signature and use it to find all the references; then delete this temp method.

Comment: you wont find those but cou can copy the method name and do a search on files to find it
another useful tip is to revert to the original method and use refactoring to add the additional paramater that will add it at all calls